# Porting from Java to Android - BufferedImage

Tags: java, android, bitmap, sprite, bufferedimage

I have a Java applet in which I am loading and animating Sprites the function looks like this:

```
public void addSprite(BufferedImage image, long duration,
        int rows, int cols, int width, int height) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            long durationFrame = (long) (duration / (cols * rows));
            addFrame(image.getSubimage(j * width, i * height,
                    width, height), durationFrame);
        }
    }
}
```

The addFrame method saves the sub-images into an ArrayList with the duration for which the image will be shown.

Everything works fine, but obviously the **BufferedImage** is not part of the Android package therefore I must modify the method using a Bitmap instead.
But I am having problems to exchange the **getSubimage** method with something similar, I think the **getPixels(...)** method of the Bitmap class should do this, but I don't know exactly how to use it correctly to get the same results, because the parameters are quite different, can someone give me a hint how I can exchange this:

```
image.getSubimage(x, y, width, height)
```

with this (supposing the getPixels() method is the right choice):

```
image.getPixels(pixels, offset, stride, x, y, width, height)
```

Already thanks for the support

Comment: Try `public static Bitmap createBitmap (Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height)`.

Comment: thanks... that was it, how stupid of me not to see this method